# Secure way of storing Private key in google oauth 2.0 server application

Tags: security, private-key, google-oauth

I'm a newbie to OAuth 2.0. Currently I am in the process of implementing OAuth 2.0 for the server to server application as mentioned in this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) . As per the link, it says to generate a Public/Private key pair. After generating the pair, the message box says that

> "The Private Key has been downloaded to your machine and serves as the
>   only copy of this key. **You are responsible for storing it securely** ".

Can anybody suggest me what are the different ways to store this private key securely and/or any reference materials to go through?
Please let me know if you need additional information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by storing in the database. We have a production database in which we had introduced two more columns to store the Client_ID and Private Key. They will not be stored as is rather, we are encrypting them and then storing. It is the applications responsibility to decrypt and use it. Please let me know if any one has a better idea.